# SVAR in R - Bmat matrix needs have same # of rows as Amat

Tags: r, covariance-matrix, matrix, vector-autoregression

I'm running an SVAR in R, following this guide: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/structural-vector-autoregression-in-r-5d6dbfc56499, with slightly different variables (CPI -> Violent Crime Rates -> Federal Funds Rate). Below are my models:

```
var1 <- VAR(ts_all,
            p = 1,
            season = NULL, 
            exog = NULL, 
            type = "const")

svar1 <- SVAR(var1,
              Amat = amat,
              Bmat = NULL,
              hessian = TRUE, 
              estmethod = c("scoring", "direct"))
```

var1 runs perfectly fine, but SVAR() fails to run and gives the following error:

```
Error in cbind(Amat, Bmat) : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

I'm wondering how to solve this error, and why this is happening. Amat is a matrix that looks like this:

```
[1,  0,  0]
[NA, 1,  0]
[NA, NA, 1]
```

Where the NA's are where the estimates should go. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My A-matrix had too many restrictions - using the formula n(n-1)/2, where n is the number of variables in the system. I only needed 3 restrictions to identify the matrix, yet I imposed 6. When I imposed only 3, my SVAR ran correctly.